# Is it possible to derive bitcoin adress from blockchain.com id?

Tags: blockchain

so here is the situation: my friend lost password to his "blockchain.com" wallet. He opened it in 2015 approx. And asked me to help get access again to it. He even doesn't remember are the funds in it. He had 3 blockchain.com accounts. To one of them he collected bitcoins from faucet freebitco.in

we have email and blockchain id (which is sent to email). support does not help.

so the question is: Is it possible to derive bitcoin adress from blockchain.com id? so we could check are there bitcoins in it and know is it worth of finding password to it or just for fun to that he lost to access to n number of bitcoins)

Answer (score 1):

No. The Blockchain.com ID is simply a random ID number that points to an encrypted copy of your wallet. Their support will not be able to help you find the addresses or gain access to the wallet even if they wanted to.

Unfortunately, if you've lost your password and your recovery key, and you can't find any backup copies of them, you're probably out of luck.